# Which of these two formats do we prefer for reference lists?

Tags: discussion, formatting

## Format #1

[image]

## Format #2

[image]

I'm not looking for a 1-dimensional poll which simply counts nothing but a single number (difference in number of upvotes) like some Meta posts across the network try to do, so much as I'm looking for reasoning so that we can come to a consensus based on the quality of arguments.

Comment: Maybe I'm overly used to standard reference formats in physics because both formats look weird to me... I typically see the volume bolded, and the year given in parentheses after the page number. The issue number is rarely included. But yeah, putting the hyperlink in the title makes sense to me. I also don't know that writing out the DOI on a website is particularly important.

Comment: @Anyon I totally agree: I'm used to seeing the year in parenthesis and the volume in bold. The userscript can easily be modified to make those enhancements. The DOI could perhaps be useful if someone wants to copy and paste it into something like sci-hub, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

There's two reasons I like Format #2 better:

- I like looking at the title of the paper more than a DOI. So I prefer the hyperlink to be on the title of the paper rather than the DOI.
- The word "References" doesn't seem to be necessary here at all, since I doubt anyone needs to be told that what comes after that word are references, but if that word is kept there I don't think it needs to take as much space as it does in Format #1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really have a strong preference for either, though I have mainly used Format 1 because I installed a [userscript](https://github.com/GaurangTandon/CitationHelperForSE) that takes in a DOI and spits out a reference in that format. I can see if I can tweak it to look more like Format 2 does. I do think having the title as the hyperlink would probably be nicer.

I do like have sections separated by headers though, similar to how most research papers are divided up where a reference section is clearly marked. I don't necessarily think the header in Format 1 is too big, but I could also reduce that to an h4 header (or just bold). But I think having a marked subsection for references makes it easier to ignore them when you don't care about them or find them when you are specifically looking for references.

##### Update

I [forked the userscript](https://github.com/TyBalduf/CitationHelperForSE) and adjusted the formatting. Now it should look like the section below.<sup>[1]</sup><sup>[2]</sup><sup>[3]</sup> After seeing, h4 and bold side by side, I settled on bold for the Reference header. The hyperlinks are now on the title.

**References**:

1. Wang, L.; Sofer, Z.; Pumera, M. [Will Any Crap We Put into Graphene Increase Its Electrocatalytic Effect?](https://doi.org/10.1021/acsnano.9b00184) *ACS Nano* **2020,** *14* (1), 21–25. DOI: 10.1021/acsnano.9b00184.
2. Upper, D. [The unsuccessful self-treatment of a case of “writer's block”1.](https://doi.org/10.1901/jaba.1974.7-497a) *J. Appl. Behav. Anal.* **1974,** *7* (3), 497–497. DOI: 10.1901/jaba.1974.7-497a.
3. Berry, M. V.; Brunner, N.; Popescu, S.; Shukla, P. [Can apparent superluminal neutrino speeds be explained as a quantum weak measurement?](https://doi.org/10.1088/1751-8113/44/49/492001) *J. Phys. A: Math. Theor.* **2011,** *44* (49), 492001. DOI: 10.1088/1751-8113/44/49/492001.

For comparison, this is what it would look like if the word "References" were to be in H4 font rather than regular font (bolded):

##### References:

1. Wang, L.; Sofer, Z.; Pumera, M. [Will Any Crap We Put into Graphene Increase Its Electrocatalytic Effect?](https://doi.org/10.1021/acsnano.9b00184) *ACS Nano* **2020,** *14* (1), 21–25. DOI: 10.1021/acsnano.9b00184.
2. Upper, D. [The unsuccessful self-treatment of a case of “writer's block”1.](https://doi.org/10.1901/jaba.1974.7-497a) *J. Appl. Behav. Anal.* **1974,** *7* (3), 497–497. DOI: 10.1901/jaba.1974.7-497a.
3. Berry, M. V.; Brunner, N.; Popescu, S.; Shukla, P. [Can apparent superluminal neutrino speeds be explained as a quantum weak measurement?](https://doi.org/10.1088/1751-8113/44/49/492001) *J. Phys. A: Math. Theor.* **2011,** *44* (49), 492001. DOI: 10.1088/1751-8113/44/49/492001.

Comment: I had a feeling that the reason for the format was because you were using a userscript! About the heading: I'd prefer getting the best balance of (1) looking nice and professional, while also (2) not taking up more space than necessary to accomplish (1). The bold heading seems okay in this case. In an answer with several H1 headings, a bigger font would seem appropriate. I prefer H4 over H3, and H5 over H4. Simply bold regular font seems to be larger than H5 or the same size, depending on how much I'm zoomed into the screen. I think bold regular font strikes the best balance, but H5 is ok too!

Comment: Great work on updating the userscript! In case anyone is looking for it, [this is the commit](https://github.com/TyBalduf/CitationHelperForSE/commit/1eddd2e8ac598f245935e70d98e7af98a325c20e) where the H3 font was changed to H4, and it would be just as easy to replace the `####` representing H4 to `**___**` representing bold font. I prefer taking up less space (i.e. using just bold font), but you seem to strongly prefer H4 over that. I've added a comparison of what they both look like, into your answer. Maybe it's since you're adjusting from H3 (which is what you've been used to for so long).

Comment: @NikeDattani After seeing them side by side, I think I agree that bold might be nicer. I updated the script again and flipped around this post to show the bold version, then the h4 version. I don't know any javascript and was able to make these changes, so if somebody has a different preference it is very straightforward to change this.